# Printing a list using reflection

Tags: java, list, reflection

```
 public class Service{ 
       String serviceName;
      //setter and getter
  }

  public class Version{ 
       int VersionID;
      //setter and getter
  }

  public void test(Object list){

        //it shd print the obtained list

   }
```

> List< Service> list1; //Service is a Bean
>        List< Version> list2; //Version is a Bean
>        test(list1);
>        test(list2);

Now the test method shd print the obtained list - (i.e) If the list is of type **Service** ,then serviceName should be printed using its getter.  If the list type is **Version** versionID should be printed.
Is it possible to achieve this without using Interface or abstract class?

Comment: your question is not clear, should it print `serviceName` or its value?

Comment: why you want to do it with reflection?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and how this relates to reflection.  Also, where does the test method live?  There are 2 classes and then a lone method.

Comment: @mtariq : serviceName value shd be printed.

Comment: @l15a : Test method is in some other class..

Comment: The thing is i dont have permission to modify the service and version class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danLeon has the simplest idea so far (adding `toString` to the classes), assuming you have access to `Service` and `Version`.

I'm not sure why you were thinking of reflection, but the only thing I can think of is that you want something that will work with any object that has a single attribute `String` getter, and then you would do something like this (crazy IMO, but it uses reflection):

```
Class clazz = list.get(0).getClass();
Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
Method onlyStringGetter = null;
for (Method method: methods) {
    String mName = method.getName();
    if (mName.matches("get\w+") {
        if (method.getReturnType().equals(String.class) {
            if (onlyStringGetter != null) thrown new RuntimeException("More than one String getter available");
            onlyStringGetter = method;
        }
    }
}
if (onlyStringGetter == null) throw new RuntimeException("No String getter found for class: " + clazz.getName());
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
for (Object singleStringAttribObj: list) {
    // some exception handling needed for below
    String result = (String)onlyStringGetter.invoke(singleStringAttribObj);
    strings.add(result);
}
System.out.println(strings);
```

I haven't compiled or tried, but that is approximately right.  Definitely some additional exception handling is required

Comment: IF version is of type Interger what to  do?

Comment: Then you don't get as specific as I did with getter return types or lists of strings. You treat everything as pure Object.class, and depend on #toString() for output.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Object instanceof List) {
    List list = (List)Object ;

   for(int index=0; index < list.length();index++) {
       Object obj = list.get(index);

       if(obj instanceof Service) {
         //cast to service and print value or use reflection
           Service service= (Service)obj ;
           System.out.println(service.geServiceName());
       } else if(obj instanceof Version) {
          // cast to Version and print versionID  someting
          Version version = (Version)obj ;
          System.out.println(version.getVersionId());
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void test(Object list) {
    if(list instanceof List)
        test((List)list);
}

public void test(List<?> list) {
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {
        Object o = list.get(0);
        if (o instanceof Version) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Version> lVersion = (List<Version>) list;
            for (Version v : lVersion) {
                System.out.println(v.getVersionID());
            }
        } else if (o instanceof Service) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            List<Service> lService = (List<Service>) list;
            for (Service s : lService) {
                System.out.println(s.getServiceName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static public class Service {

    String serviceName;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return serviceName;
    }
}

static public class Version {

    String VersionID;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return VersionID;
    }
}

static public void test(List<?> list) {
    for (Object object : list) {
        System.out.println(object.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: One more doubt, using to String i can return the string, If i have to return some Object. How to do it?