# Find out what type of list a Field is

Tags: java, class, dynamic, field

I am trying to figure out what type of class a List is implementing in my program.

I am grabbing JSON data and placing it in a root object. This root object then has Lists in it to store each element of the JSON data.

For example I have a root that has a declared fields of

```
List<Person> people
List<Location> locations
```

So what I want to be able to do is loop through each field of the root class, grab the type of class the list that I am currently looking at is, and then call a specific function for that class. (when I say specific function I mean I have an interface declared such that I can just return that class type that implements the interface and run the function that it implements to take the list apart.

calling `Class<?> clss = fieldObj.getType()` (where fieldObj is type Field) just returns that it is a list. How do I get what type of list this field is?

Comment: What do you mean by type? Implemenation `ArrayList` vs `LinkedList` or generic type `Person` vs `Location`?

Comment: Look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11264363/1065197).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the type of the object contained in the list at runtime, you cannot do so from the `List` itself. This is because of type erasure which means that at runtime all `List`s are `List<Object>`. If you need to determine the type of the object in the list, get the first element in the list and do an `instanceof` or `assignableFrom`

Comment: I ended up using this here, grabbed the list from the object, grabbed the class then created a new instance of it! perfect thanks a lot! like this better than trying to get it from the field as this allows for a gaurentee that I am getting the right class!

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.5+ it could be partially done with [`getGenericType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getGenericType%28%29) method from `Field` class.

> Field.getGenericType() will consult the Signature Attribute in the class file if it's present. If the attribute isn't available, it falls back on Field.getType() which was not changed by the introduction of generics.

See an example [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTypes.html).  Look at what the code prints for

`$ java FieldSpy FieldSpy list`

`> GenericType: java.util.List<java.lang.Integer>`